# Ninject not working with Asp.Net WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I have seen so many people ask this question and have tried what they accepted as answers but none of them have worked for me.

I keep getting this error when I try to use Ninject with my asp.net webapi

```
 { "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "An error
 occurred when trying to create a controller of type
 'SubjectPostsController'. Make sure that the controller has a
 parameterless public constructor.", "ExceptionType":
"System.InvalidOperationException", "StackTrace": " at
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
controllerType)\ \ at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
request)\ \ at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext ()",
"InnerException": { "Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Type
'Analyzer.Controllers.SubjectPostsController' does not have a default
 constructor", "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
"StackTrace": " at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\
\ at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
instanceType)\ \ atSystem.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\ \ at  System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.CreateHttpRequestMessa ge
request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
controllerType)" } }
```

My Controller:

```
using Analyzer.Models.ModelsForApp;
using Analyzer.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Analyzer.Controllers
{
    public class SubjectPostsController : ApiController
    {
        private IRepository _repo;
        public SubjectPostsController(IRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
        public IEnumerable<SubjectPost> Get()
        {
            var posts = _repo.GetSubjectPosts()
           .OrderByDescending(p =>p.Created).ToList();
            return posts;

        }
    }
}
```

The Ninject.WebCommon:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof  Analyzer.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof (Analyzer.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace Analyzer.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common;
using Analyzer.Database;
using Analyzer.Repository;
using System.Web.Http;


public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().InRequestScope();
    }        
}
```

}

The nuget packages I have installed are:

```
Ninject version 3.2.2.0
Ninject integration for WepApi2 3.2.4.0
Ninject Web Host for WebApi2 3.2.4.0
Ninject.MVC3 3.2.1.0
Ninject.Web 3.2.1.0
Ninject.Web.Common 3.2.3.0
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.2.3.0
WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject
```

So far I've tried so many possibilities,
The GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver throws an exception when I tried that method.

So basically, I've run out of ideas. Does anyone know how to solve this?

UPDATE: I tried solving this using Unity and it worked. Although I don't know the drawbacks of using unity and the amount of support it gets(It doesn't seem to have been updated for almost a year). Researching more on unity but I am still interested in a solution using Ninject.

UPDATE 2: It also works with SimpleInjector...I'm beginning to think the problem is from Ninject. Can anyone get Ninject working with WebApi?

Comment: @NightOwl888 so in my WepApiConfig.Register, should I have a code snippet like "var k = new StandardKernel(); config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(k); ?

Comment: @NigtOwl888, I tried that and got the same exception as I did when I tried using the GlobalConfiguration..."a cyclic dependency was detected.."

Comment: did this question not work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711996/mvc5-webapi2-and-ninject-parameterless-constructor-error?rq=1

Comment: @davethieben not it didn't sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        var dependencyInjectionProvider = new DependencyInjectionProvider();

        // Set MVC depencendy resolver for asp mvc web project
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(dependencyInjectionProvider.GetMvcDependencyResolver());

        // Set MVC depencendy resolver for asp mvc web API project
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = dependencyInjectionProvider.GetHttpDependencyResolver();


        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

The `DependencyInjectionProvider` has two internal components:

- `HttpDependencyResolver` Resolves injections on ApiControlelrs
- `MvcDependencyResolver` Resolves injections on Mvc controllers

You can find the full implementation at https://gist.github.com/remojansen/d907f8e2c2c4bfb7f65e

Comment: Okay, I will check this out later. Right now I have my hands full with projects. Thanks a lot for your reply and I will certainly notify you if this worked or not when I do try it out

Comment: I never did have the time to try this out and moved on with other projects and simpleInjector.

Comment: Not some solution, bu I'm not using DI in API controllers, rather invoke new instance of the implementation :)