# I am having issues with Ninject and MVC 5 Web api 2.2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject.web.mvc, ninject.web

I tried the solution in [MVC5, Web API 2 and and Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595472/mvc5-web-api-2-and-and-ninject) but the package breaks my build(System.Web). I have also tried the "Ninject.MVC3" Package. When i fix it with "Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost", I get the error:

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type error: 'AnyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

I have installed, reinstalled, uninstalled-installed all the of the packages multiple times.

My NinjectWebCommon.cs is vanilla except for the following:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
  {
    kernel.Bind<IMonitoringConfigurationService>()
    .To<MonitoringConfigurationService>();
  }
```

I Would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the cause of your problem is, as the latest releases of Ninject are virtually plug-n-play. Make sure you have installed the following Nuget packages. If you've got other versions or anything weird uninstall them:

```
Ninject
Ninject.MVC5
Ninject.Web.WebApi
Ninject.Web.Common (Added by Ninject.Web.WebApi)
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost (Added by Ninject.MVC5)
```

Anything else is unnecessary and should be removed. The last two packages are installed as dependencies, so really all you should have to install explicitly is `Ninject.MVC5` and `Ninject.Web.WebApi`. Either will install the `Ninject` base package.

Once you've got the right packages, then it basically boils down to your config in `NinjectWebCommon.cs`. The only method you need to modify is `RegisterServices`, and there, you'll need to add any and all bindings your project needs. If you're getting an error saying you need a parameterless constructor, that just means you haven't added the binding that the constructor needs.