# Parameterless constructor error when using Ninject with WebAPI on IIS, runs fine when debugging locally

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

When I run my WebAPI project from Visual Studio it runs perfectly. But when I publish to the file system and copy the files to my IIS folder and run it, it fails with the error: `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DepartmentsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

Some of the other answers on SO like this one: [MVC5, Web API 2 and and Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595472/mvc5-web-api-2-and-and-ninject)
say that you need to install Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost, which I've done.

All my bindings are set and everything is initialized in NinjectWebCommon. NinjectWebCommon.Start() is being called when I'm debugging locally. I don't know what calls it as I can't find a reference to NinjectWebCommon.Start() anywhere in the application. Why would this work in local debug but fail in IIS?

```
using System.Web.Http;
using MyApp.WebAPI.Infrastructure;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.WebAPI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(MyApp.WebAPI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace MyApp.WebAPI.App_Start {
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        public static void Start() {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            IKernel container = null;

            bootstrapper.Initialize(() => {
                container = CreateKernel();
                return container;
            });

            NinjectDependencyResolver resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }

        public static void Stop() {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        private static IKernel CreateKernel() {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
            NinjectConfigurator containerConfigurator = new NinjectConfigurator();
            containerConfigurator.Configure(kernel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is where my bindings are:

```
using MyApp.DataAccess.Entities;
using MyApp.Domain.Abstract;
using MyApp.DataAccess.Repositories.Concrete;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common;

namespace MyApp.WebAPI.App_Start {
    public class NinjectConfigurator {
        public void Configure(IKernel container) {
            AddBindings(container);
        }

        private void AddBindings(IKernel container) {
            container.Bind<MyAppContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            container.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyAppContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyAppContext>>();
            container.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
            container.Bind<ITeamRepository>().To<TeamRepository>();
            container.Bind<IDepartmentRepository>().To<DepartmentRepository>();
            container.Bind<IDivisionRepository>().To<DivisionRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using MyApp.DataAccess.Entities;
using MyApp.Domain.Abstract;
using Department = MyApp.Domain.Models.Department;

namespace MyApp.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentsController : ApiController {
        private IUnitOfWork<MyAppContext> _unitOfWork;

        public DepartmentsController(IUnitOfWork<MyAppContext> unitOfWork) {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get() {
            IEnumerable<Department> deptsList = _unitOfWork.Departments.GetAll();
            return Ok(deptsList);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
            Department dept = _unitOfWork.Departments.Get(id);
            return Ok(dept);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/departments/division/{divisionId:int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDepartmentsByDivision(int divisionId) {
            IEnumerable<Department> departmentsInDivision = _unitOfWork.Departments.GetDepartmentsByDivisionId(divisionId);
            return Ok(departmentsInDivision);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(Department department) {
            _unitOfWork.Departments.Add(department);

            //Make sure departmentId is updated from DB before passing back
            return Created("api/departments/" + department.DepartmentId, department);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult Put(Department department) {
            _unitOfWork.Departments.Update(department);
            return Ok(department);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated to include controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything started working when I used NuGet to install EntityFramework to my WebAPI project. This makes no sense and completely defeats the purpose DI/Ninject and my data access layer, but I'll take a working bad design over a "good design" that doesn't work.